# Estimote Beacon Android SDK

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote, beacon

I'm developing an Android app that uses the Estimote SDK available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK).

But I'm still not able to use my Android device (5.0.1) as advertiser to be discovered by other devices that use the Estimote app. I've tried to use QuickBeacon by [Radius Networks, Inc.](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/) but it showed a message saying that my OS on my device does not support Bluetooth LE advertising.

Please can you help me with that?

Comment: What device is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate Estimote beacons, you need to use iOS Estimote app. In that way Estimote app for Android will discover it.

Answer (score 0):

yes not all android device support Ble Advertisment.

you can check list of devices on this link which are supported.

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html

Answer (score 0):

Not all Android devices supports BLE advertisement, you can check it using this callback. Also you can simulate Estimote's iBeacon (or any other beacons) using simple Linux command from Bluez lib:

```
  UUID="B9 40 7F 30 F5 F8 46 6E AF F9 25 55 6B 57 FE 6D"
    MAJOR="00 01"
    MINOR="00 02"
```

sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 $UUID $MAJOR $MINOR C82.